# I want to increase JButton with for loop. How can I do?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jbutton

I want to increase JButton with for loop but this program output wrote just "i". I want to write output "1", "2",...."10" in this program. So I understood that I don't write correct this `frame.add(new JButton("i"));`.
What should I do?

```
public static void main(String[]args){
   
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(500,500);
    frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    
    for(int i = 0; i<10;i++){
        frame.add(new JButton("i"));
    }

    frame.setVisible(true);
    
}
```

Comment: `new JButton(String.valueOf(i))` or `new JButton(""+i)`

Comment: what is a _JButton objectiv_?

Answer (score 1):

Define the `JButton` object and add the text you want using `setText()` method

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  JButton jButton = new JButton();
  jButton.setText(String.valueOf(i));
  frame.add(jButton);
}
```

Comment: You can pass the text using `JButton` constructor: the body of the for-loop needs to be: `frame.add(new JButton(String.valueOf(i)));`